# Callback result to a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to callback a result to a function.

I tried the following:

```
function multiply(x,y, callback) {
     let res = x * y
     callback(res)
 }

 function hardOperation(a,b) {
     let res = a + b + multiply(a,b)
    console.log("The result is " + res)
}

hardOperation(2,2)
```

However, I am getting:

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Do I need to define a global variable or can I also pass the `res` back to the function?

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a function which will retrieve the callbacked value.

```
function multiply(x,y, callback) {
     let res = x * y
     callback(res)
 }

 function hardOperation(a,b) {
     multiply(a, b, function(res){
        res = a + b + res
        console.log("The result is " + res);
     })

}

hardOperation(2,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`callback` is indeed not a function, because you don't define it.  The function you're calling expects three arguments:

```
function multiply(x,y, callback) {
```

You're giving it only two:

```
multiply(a,b)
```

So the third argument is `undefined`.  You're also expecting it to return a value, but nowhere in the `multiply` function is anything returned.  So that return value will *also* be `undefined`.

The `multiply()` function is attempting to demonstrate the use of a callback function *in place of* returning a value.  This is a common pattern for asynchronous code, for example.  So instead of relying on a return value, supply it with a function to perform the action on the result.  Something like this:

```
function hardOperation(a,b) {
    multiply(a,b, function (res) {
        res = a + b + res;
        console.log("The result is " + res);
    });
}
```